# div sidebar overlapping body

Tags: css, html, layout, sidebar

The sidebar is overlapping the body. I need push the body div according to the side bar div and so as its background. I have a jsfiddle link  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/asdfqwer/qkNTu/) of which the html code is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top_block lo2_header">
        <div class="content">
            asdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadf<br>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <div>
    <div class="background lo2_lbar">
    </div>
    <div class="left_block lo2_lbar">
        <div class="content">asdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasda
        asdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdasdfasdfasdfasdf<br>
        asdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdasdfasdfasdfasdf<br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background lo2_body">
    </div>
    <div class="center_block lo2_body">
        <div class="content">lo2_body
        asd<br> asd<br>asd<br>asd<br>asd<br>asd<br>asd<br>asd<br>   asd<br>asd<br>asd<br>asd<br>asd<br>asd<br>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom_block lo2_footer">
        <div class="content">lo2_footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't try and sidestep the SO rule of posting your code in your question when linking to jsFiddle.net. If jsFiddle.net is inaccessible for any reason then your question loses all value.

Comment: Link links to jfiddle, should be jsfiddle.

Comment: Here is the correct link to the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/asdfqwer/qkNTu/

Answer (score 0):

Because what you have in there is just 3 words!

`asdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasda` is a really long word.

Comment: I wanted the body div to start after the long word basically

Comment: @user3075289 Try to draw this on MS Paint and show us what you exactly want. What do you mean `body div`?

Comment: I just changed the jsfiddle, Iam trying to design a layout where my side bar should push the body to show completely, and I am having background for both sidebar and body that should adjust

Comment: For that same effect, all you really have to do is only push the body to right side with the sidebar in the back. I suggest you use `-webkit-transform: translate3d(250px, 0,0)` or something similar to create that effect. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/vishl/wzPSF/

Comment: I changed the jsfiddle - I can push the body, but cannot align the entire body to a square shape,

Comment: @user3075289 Please reread my previous comment. And this time consider using percentages instead of pixels so your website can resize accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
width:900px;
background:#e9e9e9;
height:400px;
}


.content{
float:left;
width:65%;
margin-left:3%;
background:red;
height:100%;
}




#header{
width:100%;
height:20%;
background:blue;
margin-bottom:1%;
}

#wrapper{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#container{
width:100%;
height:60%;
margin-bottom:1%;
}



.sidebar{
  float:left;
width:25%;
margin-left:1%;
background:yellow;
height:100%;
}

#footer{
margin-top:3px;
clear:both;
background:#FF8C00;
width:100%;
height:10%;

 }
```

Comment: From the look of what i saw, i tried recreating something similar